# How do I tell django to use the PostgreSQL DATE function in Django's .annotate()?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models, group-by

Suppose I have the model `EventDateTime`, which has a foreign key to a page as well as a date field. i.e. pages can have multiple `EventDateTime` of different dates and times:

Model code looks roughly like this:

```
class EventDateTime(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey("Event", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="dates")
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)
    # Some other unrelated fields

class Event(Page):
    # Some unrelated fields
```

The way the site will work, is that it will show users a certain number of events (say 10) within a certain time, with multiple occurrences of events on the same day ignored (but not across multiple days). Basically this SQL query:

```
SELECT page_id, DATE(MIN(date)) 
FROM eventdatetime 
WHERE (date >= '2020-01-05 17:45:48.545123')  
GROUP BY page_id, DATE(date) 
ORDER BY date 
LIMIT 10;
```

Which could return for example:

```
 page_id |    date
---------+------------
     296 | 2020-01-07
     301 | 2020-01-07
     298 | 2020-01-09
     289 | 2020-01-10
     266 | 2020-01-11
     267 | 2020-01-11
     268 | 2020-01-11
     269 | 2020-01-11
      54 | 2020-01-13
     290 | 2020-01-13
```

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to translate this exact intent into Django's ORM:

```
EventDateTime.objects\
    .filter(page__live=True,date__gte=datetime.now())\
    .values('page_id')\
    .annotate(Min('date__date')).order_by('date')
```

This is the returned SQL:

```
SELECT "web_eventdatetime"."page_id", 
    MIN("web_eventdatetime"."date") AS "date__date__min" 
FROM "web_eventdatetime" 
INNER JOIN "web_event" ON ("web_eventdatetime"."page_id" = "web_event"."page_ptr_id") 
INNER JOIN "wagtailcore_page" ON ("web_event"."page_ptr_id" = "wagtailcore_page"."id") 
WHERE ("web_eventdatetime"."date" >= 2020-01-05 18:07:57.516323 AND "wagtailcore_page"."live" = True) 
GROUP BY "web_eventdatetime"."page_id", 
    "web_eventdatetime"."date" <-- does not extract date portion
ORDER BY "web_eventdatetime"."date" ASC
```

Notice how in the second to last line for some reason Django does not understand my intent of grouping by `DATE(MIN(date))` instead of `MIN(date)` (which unfortunately makes a difference in this case). :(

How would I tell Django to group by only the date portion, not the whole datetime?

Comment: Can you show your model code?

Comment: Looks like that here `date__gte=datetime.now()` you need `date__gte=datetime.now().date()`.

Comment: @funnydman Good catch :) Although it does depends on if I'm showing events that happened earlier today or not (both cases exist). Either way, it still doesn't change the `GROUP BY` portion of the query which aggregates by `date` and not by `MIN(DATE(date))` like I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add explicitly the date field with a date lookup in values expression. This will group on the date part of the date field of the queryset.

```
 .values('page_id', 'date__date')
```